# no ABI error , when creating an Android virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am getting a No ABI error when creating a virtual device. My setup includes

Android SDK

ADT plugin

Eclipse

when I run

```
 android list targets
```

it gives me

```
  Name: Android 4.0.3
  Type: Platform
  API level: 15
  Revision: 2
  Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720,
  WXGA800
 ABIs : no ABIs.
```

and when I try to run

```
  android create avd -n myandroid -t 1
```

it gives

```
  This platform has more than one ABI. Please specify one using --abi.
```

how do I specify ABI and hence create an AVD

Comment: maybe you need the "ARM EABI v7a System Image" too

Answer (score 58):

**Find the ABI relative to your android version:**

```
android list sdk --extended --no-ui --all
```

**Install ABI:**

```
echo "y" | android update sdk -a --no-ui --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22,sys-img-x86_64-android-22
```

**Create AVD:**

```
echo "n" | android create avd --name myandroid22 -t "android-22"
```

**If you have more than one, list and find valid ABI:**

```
android list targets
```

**Create AVD:**

```
echo "n" | android create avd --name myandroid22 -t "android-22" --abi "default/armeabi-v7a"
```

Comment: It is not working for me. I am getting the error "Valid ABIs: no ABIs.
Error: Invalid --abi armeabi-v7a for the selected target.
"

Comment: You are probably getting the "no ABIs" again because you are not installing the images in the correct order. You should first install "android-22" then "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22" and "sys-img-x86_64-android-22". If you do it the other way, you get a failure at installing sys-img because the pre-requisites are not met.

Answer (score 20):

Use the command **tools/android** to fire up the **Android SDK Manager** and install the ABI's from there.

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Answer (score 4):

Use "android list targets" to get a list of possible target configurations.

When using the command to create a virtual device use -t to specify the id from the list and -b to specify the ABI. You can see that in the result for the "list target" command.

```
$ android create avd -n my_android1.1 -t 1 -b default/x86
$ android list target

----------
id: 1 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 4
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86
----------
id: 2 or "android-20"
     Name: Android 4.4W.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 20
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
----------
```