# create and activate avd for android in command line inside docker

Tags: android, command-line, automation, automated-tests, android-virtual-device

I am running android on my docker and I need to use AVD to run. And whenever  I try to create and run an avd I got the error

```
Valid ABIs: no ABIs.
Error: Invalid --abi armeabi-v7a for the selected target.
```

And I tried to install ABIs and it does not seems like working. The thing is I should do the whole steps using command line. And the android sdk version is **android-sdk_r24.4.1**. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019532/no-abi-error-when-creating-an-android-virtual-device) and did not work for me. It would be great if some one come give a helping hand. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Run next command to see emulator architecture images available to download:

`android list sdk --all --extended`

```
----------
id: 45 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-tv-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image
           Revision 3
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
id: 46 or "sys-img-x86-android-tv-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image
           Revision 3
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
id: 47 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-wear-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image
           Revision 3
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
id: 48 or "sys-img-x86-android-wear-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image
           Revision 3
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
id: 49 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: ARM EABI v7a System Image
           Revision 3
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
id: 50 or "sys-img-x86_64-android-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
           Revision 9
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
id: 51 or "sys-img-x86-android-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Intel x86 Atom System Image
           Revision 9
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
id: 52 or "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image
           Revision 14
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
id: 53 or "sys-img-x86_64-google_apis-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
           Revision 14
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
----------
id: 54 or "sys-img-x86-google_apis-23"
     Type: SystemImage
     Desc: Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image
           Revision 14
           Requires SDK Platform Android API 23
```

Download desired image with next command:

`echo y | android update sdk --all --no-ui --filter "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-23"`

After downloading run next command to see available targets:

`android list targets`

```
id: 5 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 6.0 (API level 23)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : google_apis/x86
```

Put desired tag/abi during creation of emulator image:

`echo "no" | android -v create avd --force -n arm -t "android-23" --abi "google_apis/armeabi-v7a"`

Google changes default tag/api from version to version and shifts play services image under different names, so you have to run and carefully check the output of the commands above to see the actual picture. Hope it helps.