# install avd from command line

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator, terminal-emulator

I am running an Android application and have to use command line to create and activate AVD. I have the same problem described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019532/no-abi-error-when-creating-an-android-virtual-device) link but it is not working for me. It is kinda blocker and it would be great if someone give a helping hand to fix the issue.

I run this command to create the avd:

```
android create avd --name myandroid22 -t "android-22"
```

And for that, the response is:

```
Valid ABIs: no ABIs. Error: This platform has more than one ABI. Please specify one using --abi.
```

And after that I have tried to install ABIs by using the command:

```
android update sdk -a --no-ui --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-21,sys-img-x86_64-android-21
```

Even after this got installed the same as before is raising.

List of ABIs installed:

```
android list targets

id: 1 or "android-21" Name: Android 5.0.1 Type: Platform API level: 21 Revision: 2 Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
```

Even after installing the ABI earlier

Comment: Please write the steps and command line executions you're doing actually.

Comment: android create avd --name myandroid22 -t "android-22" command to create the avd. And for that the response is "Valid ABIs: no ABIs.
Error: This platform has more than one ABI. Please specify one using --abi.
"

Comment: Which are your installed ABIs?. List here using this command: android list targets

Comment: It shows like   id: 1 or "android-21"
     Name: Android 5.0.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 21
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
Even after installing the ABIs

Comment: It is the same before installing the ABIs.

Answer (score 3):

I created the emulator by doing the following steps:

1. I ran the command `android list sdk --extended --no-ui --all` and find the suitable ABI for the sdk. In my case it was **sys-img-x86_64-android-21**.
2. Following that I ran the command `android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "sys-img-x86_64-android-21"`.
3. And then I have double checked whether the ABI parameter updated by running the command `android list targets`.
4. Finally created the emulator by running the command `echo no | android create avd --name myAvd -t 1 --abi default/x86_64`.

And to double check whether the new emulator is created or not, the following commands can be used `emulator -list-avds` and `android list avd`