# Android and Eclipse, ABI type

Tags: android, eclipse, abi

So I am trying to create a new android virtual device instance at Eclipse and I have the message

**You must select one ABI type to create an AVD.
If none are available, use the Android SDK Manager to download the ABI**

At the select box there is no ABI type,how can I download a ABI type.I open the SDK manager but I do not know how to download an ABI type

Comment: Eclipse is no longer supported by Google for Android development. if you are just starting you should use Android Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no ABI error , when creating an Android virtual device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019532/no-abi-error-when-creating-an-android-virtual-device)

Comment: The problem is that I have 2GB RAM at my PC and Android Studio needs 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

The ABI is basically the instruction set of the cpu.
You need to download the ABIs you want to support in your app. Usually this is ARM, but the more you can support, the better ofcourse.

Here you can find more information and the possible ABI types.
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html

Try to find these in the SDK manager.

About your comment suggesting you can not use Android Studio;
The minimum requirements are listed here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#SystemRequirements

> System Requirements
>   Windows
>
> Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10 (32- or 64-bit)
>       2 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
>       2 GB of available disk space minimum,
>       4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
>       1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution
>       For accelerated emulator: 64-bit operating system and Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
>
> Mac
>
> Mac® OS X® 10.8.5 or higher, up to 10.11.4 (El Capitan)
>       2 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
>       2 GB of available disk space minimum,
>       4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
>       1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution
>
> Linux
>
> GNOME or KDE desktop
>
> Tested on Ubuntu® 12.04, Precise Pangolin (64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications)
>       64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications
>       GNU C Library (glibc) 2.11 or later
>       2 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
>       2 GB of available disk space minimum,
>       4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
>       1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution
>       For accelerated emulator: Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality, or AMD processor with support for AMD Virtualization™ (AMD-V™)

Comment: I have 2 (1.86 used) GB RAM,so I have the minimum as I see

Answer (score 0):

Please use Android Studio - official IDE for Android.

Eclipse Android Developer Tools plug-in is no longer supported:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html

Comment: Right after it stops sucking.